# Creating a speech recognition system for the Malinké language

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, voice

I want to create a speech recognition system for my native language ([Malinké](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandinka_people)). How can I get what I say recognized in my language? Is there already a platform that allows me to record the phonetics of my language and transcribe it to text?

Comment: You may want to specify your language in the question.

Comment: It is a local African language.

Comment: Which one? This is important to know as somebody already might have implemented that before.

Comment: I don't find it anywhere(Language is Malinké).

Comment: You need to gather data (transcriptions and audio) from Malinke language. Then you can follow this tutorial using the deepspeech library: https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/tutorial-how-i-trained-a-specific-french-model-to-control-my-robot/22830

Answer (score 0):

Speech recognition is a very [non-trivial](http://www.speech.kth.se/~rolf/gslt_papers/MarkusForsberg.pdf) task. If you really want to create such a system, you will need many samples from native speakers. Once collected, a framework such as [DeepSpeech](https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech) from Mozilla might be a good starting point for you.

Mozilla also has another project called ["Common Voice"](https://voice.mozilla.org/en) which lets you donate voice samples to help create better voice recognition systems. However, they are really struggling to obtain data as you can see [here](https://voice.mozilla.org/en/languages). The smaller the community of native speakers, the harder it will be to create a good system.